# reading text file and get Distance value by HashMap

Tags: java

I've this Text file (dis.txt) contain:

```
    1="A" (Z75)(T118)(S140)
    2="B" (U85)(G90)(F211)(P101)
    3="C" (P138)(D120)(R146)
    4="D" (M75)
```

these number are distance for Example distance between A & Z is 75

and I wont to read these  distance and cities like (Z75)(T118)(S140) by java program I think HashMap good for my problem after I created HashMap as you see I wrote         myMap.get("A"); I wont to give me the result (Z75)(T118)(S140) .
I hope you understand my problem thanks..

```
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Properties;

    public class nodes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties pro = new Properties();
    {

    try {
    pro.load(new FileInputStream("dis"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 13; i++) {
    String abu = pro.getProperty("" + i);
    //System.out.println(abu);
    }
    HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myMap.get("A");
    myMap.get("B");
    myMap.get("C");
    myMap.get("D");


    System.out.println(myMap.get("A"));
    System.out.println(myMap.get("B"));
    System.out.println(myMap.get("C"));
    System.out.println(myMap.get("D"));


    }
    }

    }
```

Comment: this is for AI (Artificial Intelligent) project by java

Comment: where did you populate your hashmap ??... i cant see any code :P

Comment: but I created mymap by hashMap

Comment: @jangiz.. Just creating a Map, does not store your values into it. You actually need to populate it.

Comment: sorry i don't understand you. can you explain more clear?

Comment: @jangiz. When you create an array like: - `int[] arr = new int[5];`, is it populated with your data? No, right. You need to put data explicitly. Same is the case with `Map`, or any collection. Just think, you have a `Piggy Bank`. Until you put some money into it, you can't get money out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need to populate your HashMap before you can get any data back from it.

In the loop, where you are reading value for each property, put the data in your `Map`.
And always use `abstract` type for your `reference type` on your `LHS`. Use `Map` instead of `HashMap`.

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) {  // Start loop from 1, as properties in txt file are from 1
    String abu = pro.getProperty("" + i);  

   // Split the string on space, and put 1st and 2nd element of array 
   // as `key-value` pair in HashMap
   String[] arr = abu.split(" ");
   myMap.put(arr[0], arr[1]);
}

// Now you can fetch the data
for (String str: myMap.keySet()) {
     System.out.println(myMap.get(str));
}
```

Comment: Ok, what does your `abu` string contains? Doesn't it contains: - `"A (Z75)(T118)(S140)"`? Print it and see what it contains.

Comment: You got NPE because your loop starts with `0`, and you have not property for `0`, in your file. Start your loop with `1`. It would work.

Comment: there is no error but program doesn't run because of this code       String[] arr = abu.split(" ");
and in the Exception appear this error
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at nodes.main(nodes.java:30)

Comment: @jangiz. Yeah, see my edited code to remove that error. See the reason in my previous comment.

Comment: you right, 
after i changed 0 --> 1 these no any error and no out put in the result appear Null value

Comment: @jangiz.. Yeah because you are having `"A"` as key, and you are trying to fetch value for `A`. You can iterate over your keyset, and print the values. Using loop. Or use `myMap.get("\"A\"");`

Comment: @jangiz.. You need to use `LinkedHashMap` instead of `HashMap` on RHS, if you want to maintain the insertion order.